# Select an entire row in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Good Day

I would like to select a row from a table. Let us have this table for example:

```
| index | col1 | col2 | col3 |
-------------------------------
| 100   | 10   | 15   | 20   |
-------------------------------
```

Now I want to select the row with index 100.
Let us say that I now have another table:

```
| newCol1 | Ranked  | 
----------------------
| col1    | 1       | 
----------------------
| col2    | 2       | 
----------------------
| col3    | 3       | 
----------------------
```

Where the values 1, 2 and 3 is a ranked version of the row that was selected from the first table.
Any help would be appreciated as I am new to PowerBI

I tried using the Filter option, such that I have:

```
Ranked = RankX(table2, Filter(table1, table1[Index]=100),,ASC,Skip)
```

and I am returned with the error of "The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value."

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the filter but you didn't provide the condition.

**If you want to use Power Query :**

[image]

[image]

and then create a calculaed column for the ranking :

```
Rank = RANKX(ALL('TableSOF'), 'TableSOF'[Value], , ASC, Dense)
```

[image]

**If you want to use DAX :**

You can use a calculated column :

```
UnpivotedTableSOF = 
UNION(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(TableSOF2, TableSOF2[index] = 100), "newCol1", "col1", "Value", TableSOF2[col1]),
    SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(TableSOF2, TableSOF2[index] = 100), "newCol1", "col2", "Value", TableSOF2[col2]),
    SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(TableSOF2, TableSOF2[index] = 100), "newCol1", "col3", "Value", TableSOF2[col3])
)
```

and then create a calculated column for the ranking :

```
Rank = RANKX(ALL('UnpivotedTableSOF'), 'UnpivotedTableSOF'[Value], , ASC, Dense)
```

[image]